# How can I access the /etc of a pulled servicemix image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-servicemix

I need to install a custom bundle in a dockerized servicemix image. To do so, I need to paste some files in the /etc directory of the servicemix image. 
Could anyone help me doing this?

I've tried using the Dockerfile as follows:
But it simply doesn't work. I've looked through the documentation of the image, and the author tells me to use the command: docker run --volumes-from servicemix-data -it ubuntu bash and inspect the /servicemix, but it's empty.

```
    Dockerfile:
    FROM dskow/apache-servicemix
    WORKDIR .
    COPY ./docs /apache-servicemix/etc
```

...

```
    Command suggested by the author:
    docker run --volumes-from servicemix-data -it ubuntu bash
```

Comment: the command goes like COPY ./docs /etc every dockerfile only creates one image therefore referencing it is unneccessary (and doesnt work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unfamiliar with this approach but, having looked at the source ([link](https://hub.docker.com/r/dskow/apache-servicemix#data-peristence)), I think this is what you want to do:

Create a container called `servicemix-data` that will become your volume:

```sh
docker run --name servicemix-data -v /servicemix busybox
```

Confirm this worked:

```sh
docker container ls --format="{{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}" --all
42b3bc4dbedf    servicemix-data
...
```

Then you want to copy the files into this container:

```sh
docker cp ./docs servicemix-data:/etc
```

Finally, run `servicemix` using this container (with your files) as the source for its data:

```sh
docker run \
--detach \
--name=servicemix \
--volumes-from=servicemix-data \
dskow/apache-servicemix
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks very much, shed some good light over the problem, but when I try using your last command I get a response like: 7e9bde0b77c6fde068b243a829e2898b7bc29b41c46447cd3172a8a993a9ae2c and it doesn't launch the servicemix...

Comment: That's good and indicates that the container is running. You should then be able to browse it per the instructions you were following. `docker container ls` should show it. I noticed there's no port published in the instructions, you may need to add `--publish=8081:8081` then try browsing localhost:8081

Comment: If you'd like to see the container's output, drop `--detach` and add `--interactive --tty` when you run it.

Comment: Hello there, sorry for the late response but I got caught up and could only read this input today. I've used the --interactive --tty but the bundle still won't work, Is there any way for me to check if the ./docs was properly copied into the servicemix /etc?

Answer (score 0):

Changes in the container will be lost until it is committed back to the image.

You can use this docker file https://hub.docker.com/r/mkroli/servicemix/dockerfile and your copy statement just before the ENTRYPOINT.

```
COPY ./docs /opt/apache-servicemix/etc
```